# Limit of partition value that can be sync in same time in mongo realm sync

Tags: android, ios, mongodb, realm, mongodb-realm

I want to sync different partition values at same time. Let’s say may partition key is partition and an I have different values. I want to sync public,user,teamA,teamB`,… .
What’s the limit for this?
Is there any limit in Mongo Atlas side that can stop me from syncing partition?
If no, Is there any suggestion from limit in client side that can cause performance issues?

Comment: There is no limit you'll run into and how much data you sync is only limited by your disk space. Does that answer the question?

Comment: @Jay No you are talking about amount of data that can sync which definitely depends on disk limit. My question is more about number of partition that you can have open in same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on [Andrew_Morgan](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/u/Andrew_Morgan/) answer to [my question](https://developer.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/limit-of-partition-value-that-can-be-sync-in-same-time/106113) on mongo developer form it's good to won't have more than 10 open realm per device.

> The limit you might hit will be on the number of partitions that a given device has open at any given time – as always, mileage varies, but if you stay at 10 open realms/partitions per app/device then you should be fine.